# fftw loop execution issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, for-loop, fftw

I have a section of code where I am trying to execute FFTs in a loop. The first loop executes correctly however the subsequent iterations do not. My code is a s follows (please excuse the weird syntax, I have been trying to debug).

```
//setup FFTW
fftw_complex *d_dataBuf = fftw_alloc_complex(dataLen);
fftw_plan fftPlan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(dataLen, d_dataBuf, d_dataBuf, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

//compute the FFTs
for (int jdx = 0; jdx < numChannels; jdx++)
{

    //copy data to doubles
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < dataLen; idx++)
    {
        *(d_dataBuf + idx)[0] = data[jdx][idx].real();
        *(d_dataBuf + idx)[1] = data[jdx][idx].imag();

    }

    //perform FFT
    fftw_execute(fftPlan);

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < dataLen; idx++)
    {
        d_freqBuff[jdx][idx].real(*(d_dataBuf + idx)[0]);
        d_freqBuff[jdx][idx].imag(*(d_dataBuf + idx)[1]);

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I am using visual studio 2013

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The function spits out garbage on a large portion of the returned array elements (p.s. it works when I use an out-of-place fft)

Comment: I can't see why you'd get an error but can I ask why, if you are copying the data around you are doing an in-place in the first place.  Surely you could save a bit of time by just using an out-of-place in the first place.  Further to that you do realise you can, on nearly all implementations, cast a std::complex array to an fftw_complex array?  You could make your code run much faster doing this ...

Comment: I was worried that it might interfere with the SSE optimization as the vectors aren't aligned data, as well as the data conming in is comprised of complex<short> (and the rest is the weird syntax I was speaking about)... but thanks I think that is a far better solution to trying to get an in place working.